# Следующая строка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть такой код:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var string = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('div pre').length; i++){
    string += document.querySelectorAll('div pre')[i].innerHTML
  };
  console.log(string);
};
```

```html
<div>
  <pre>document.getElementById('mchatMsgF').focus();</pre>
  <pre>document.getElementById('mchatMsgF').value+='turgor128, ';</pre>
  <pre>return false;</pre>
</div>

<button>Кнопка</button>
```

И при клике на кнопку, оно вставляет текст из **pre** в .
Но есть проблема^ оно копирует его в виде одной строки:

```
document.getElementById('mchatMsgF').focus();document.getElementById('mchatMsgF').value+'turgor128, ';return false;
```

Как сделать, что бы оно код из каждого **pre**, вставляло на новую строку. Вот так:

```
document.getElementById('mchatMsgF').focus();
document.getElementById('mchatMsgF').value+'turgor128,';
return false;
```

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать? По-моему это плохая идея вообще.

Comment: А почему бы Вам просто при клике на кнопку не выполнять этот код? Объясните, что Вы вообще хотите получить?

Comment: @Юра Спивак добавьте "\n", удачного вам выстрела себе в ногу.

Comment: Как сделать, что бы оно код из каждого pre, вставляло на новую строку!!!
Почему вы такие ***?!
Можете показать как это сделать?

Comment: @Юра Спивак, не нервничайте, вам уже все написали выше.

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**\n** это символ переноса на новую строку

Answer (score 0):

Всё решается добавлением [`\n`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_newline.asp):

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var pre = document.querySelectorAll('div pre'),
      string = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < pre.length; i++){
    string += pre[i].innerText + '\n';
  };
  console.log(string);
};
```

```html
<div>
  <pre>document.getElementById('mchatMsgF').focus();</pre>
  <pre>document.getElementById('mchatMsgF').value+='turgor128, ';</pre>
  <pre>return false;</pre>
</div>

<button>Кнопка</button>
```